# req.isAuthenticated() is returning true even after wrong password is entered

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js, passport-local

I am using passport local strategy to authenticate the users, here is my login code:

```
app.post("/login",function(req,res){
  const user = new model({
    username:req.body.username,

    password:req.body.password,
  });


        req.login(user, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            res.render("login",{error: err});
            } else {
              passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {

                res.redirect("/dashboard");
              });
              }
      });

});
```

Now if I enter an incorrect password then an unauthorized message comes and then if I go to my dashboard route then req.isAuthenticated() is true,

here is my dashboard code:

```
app.get("/dashboard",function(req,res){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
//mywork
}
```

How to solve this problem and how/where to handle that unauthorized message?

```
passport.use(model.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(model.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(model.deserializeUser());
```

and

```
app.use(session({

secret: "secret",
resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false,

}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `req.login`. Do you know what it does? Here is how you handle you'r issues, first you create a strategy ( obviously you have a user model ).

```
const User = require('../models/User');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

/**
 * Sign in using Email and Password.
 */
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
  User.findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { msg: `Email ${email} not found.` });
    }
    if (!user.password) {
      return done(null, false, { msg: 'Your account was registered using a sign-in provider. To enable password login, sign in using a provider, and then set a password under your user profile.' });
    }
    user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      }
      return done(null, false, { msg: 'Invalid email or password.' });
    });
  });
}));
```

Then in your controller you can create a login method:

```
/**
 * POST /login
 * Sign in using email and password.
 */
exports.postLogin = (req, res, next) => {
  const validationErrors = [];
  if (!validator.isEmail(req.body.email)) validationErrors.push({ msg: 'Please enter a valid email address.' });
  if (validator.isEmpty(req.body.password)) validationErrors.push({ msg: 'Password cannot be blank.' });

  if (validationErrors.length) {
    req.flash('errors', validationErrors);
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }
  req.body.email = validator.normalizeEmail(req.body.email, { gmail_remove_dots: false });

  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('errors', info);
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      req.flash('success', { msg: 'Success! You are logged in.' });
      res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

To make sure you'r routes are authenticated:

```
app.get('/', homeController.index);
app.get('/login', userController.getLogin);
app.post('/login', userController.postLogin);
app.get('/logout', userController.logout);
app.get('/forgot', userController.getForgot);
app.post('/forgot', userController.postForgot);
app.get('/reset/:token', userController.getReset);
app.post('/reset/:token', userController.postReset);
app.get('/signup', userController.getSignup);
app.post('/signup', userController.postSignup);
app.get('/account/verify', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.getVerifyEmail);
app.get('/account/verify/:token', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.getVerifyEmailToken);
app.get('/account', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, userController.getAccount);
```

And your app settings for passport strategy session:

```
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  cookie: { maxAge: 1209600000 }, // two weeks in milliseconds
  store: new MongoStore({
    url: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
    autoReconnect: true,
  })
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.path === '/api/upload') {
    // Multer multipart/form-data handling needs to occur before the Lusca CSRF check.
    next();
  } else {
    lusca.csrf()(req, res, next);
  }
});
app.use(lusca.xframe('SAMEORIGIN'));
app.use(lusca.xssProtection(true));
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // After successful login, redirect back to the intended page
  if (!req.user
    && req.path !== '/login'
    && req.path !== '/signup'
    && !req.path.match(/^\/auth/)
    && !req.path.match(/\./)) {
    req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;
  } else if (req.user
    && (req.path === '/account' || req.path.match(/^\/api/))) {
    req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl;
  }
  next();
});
```